# how to get the center point of a scrollview subview relative to scrollview superview?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a scollView(the blue one showing in the image below) containing 20 subviews(the white view).[image]

the superView of scrollView is called pView, for example, the the center point of white view1 relative to pView is (10,10), and the center point of view6 is (496,10), after I scroll this the view as following:
[image]

the center point of view 6 is (10,10), but I don't know how to get it.

maybe I should use code like

```
        CGPoint centerPoint = [view6 convertPoint:view6.center toView:pView];
```

but I didn't get the right point

Answer (score 3, accepted):

view6.center is in the coordinate system of the superview of view6 (which is the UIScrollView).  Try

`CGPoint centerPoint = [scrollView convertPoint:view6.center toView:pView];`